# Convert .pptx or .ppt files to mp4 on Ubuntu

Tags: video, libreoffice, convert, microsoft-powerpoint

I have few slides sent by my professor. In those slides, each slide is embeded with an audio file. I want to view them as a video file.

In `Microsoft Office PowerPoint` for Windows, there is an option in `export as` to convert it to `.mp4` format. What it does is make the slide as the image and puts the recorded voice as the audio file. And the output is a `.mp4` file.

Is this type of export possible on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I have `LibreOffice Impress` in which under `export as` options, there is only a`.pdf` format option.

Comment: Save it as PDF. Using `ffmpeg`, convert each page to an image. Then again using `ffmpeg`, combine all images to form a video. 
If you use this often, write a script to do this. Let me know if you need help in doing so.

Comment: @SeverusTux but what about the voice recordings?

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Comment: @AliTou not yet more the people upvote this, more are the chances of getting the answer

Comment: @AbhayPatil You have another (late) answer. How did you solve?

Answer (score 1):

I use a workaround with the screen recording application - [SimpleScreenRecorder](https://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/)

- start your presentation in the full screen mode
- start recording
- stop recording when it's done

It will allow you to record the presentation with animation/video in a mp4-file. But unfortunately I didn't manage to record the sound.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, I know. At the moment this possibility seems that has not been *directly-implemented*.

#### Openoffice Extensions

You may give it a look to the [**impress video converter**](https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/impress-video-converter) extension.

#### Command line with `ffmpeg`

You can export the `ppt(x)` as `pdf`, `sfw`, `gif`, **`png`**, `jpg`, whatever..., and then convert the result in a video. (You may need imagemagick).

Assuming you have installed on your system the right codecs (libx264 or better, I refer here explicitly to the encoding libraries) and that the images are named `picture01.png` ...
you can use a command line similar to the following one:

```
ffmpeg -r 1/10 -i picture-%01d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mp4
```

- `-c:v libx264` : Output video codec (i.e h264) but if you have h265 is better.
- `-r 1/10` : Display each image for 10 seconds.
- `-r 30` : framerate of output video.
- `-pix_fmt yuv420p` : Output video resolution (not really needed)

There are tons of options. Moreover, with `ffmpeg` it is also possible to **add audio tracks** to a video.
For example to add the audio of the file `input.mp3` you can use:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i input.mp3 -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 output.mp4
```

Again there are tons of options (you can compact in only one command line, stretch the audio ...)

**Bonus**: the following line will **shorten** of 20% a video and audio (note atempo=1.25 is
1./0.80 where 0.80 is the compressing ratio for video --  useless complication but it works in this way).

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4  -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.8*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=1.25[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]"  output_02.mp4
```

#### Video Editing Programs

As you see this is a path that may lead to use video editing programs such as `avidemux`, `kdenlive`...

#### ScreenRecorder

You can use a Screen Recorder (also know as [screencast programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screencast)) as suggested from the other answer.
Here a [Comparison of screencasting software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_screencasting_software) by wikipedia.

#### Video conferencing software

There is a wide number of Video conferencing software that allows to share your screen, add your audio and record the session. Pick one.
(Among the others:
Zoho Meeting,
Zoom,
FreeConference.com,
BigBlueButton,
FreeConferenceCall.com,
Jitsi,
Lifesize,
Cisco WebEx,
Google Meet,
Skype,
GoToMeeting,
Microsoft Teams,
Whereby)

It may be useful the wiki [List of video telecommunication services and product brands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_telecommunication_services_and_product_brands).
Read the user agreement for any aspect related to confidentiality and privacy.

#### The World **WIDE** Web

A good number of sites offer for free and online the possibility to *convert* a powerpoint to mp4. A simple search on your preferred search engine will show you a bunch of them... and all your intentions of confidentiality and privacy may RIP.

#### References (Some words more)

1. [How To Create A Video From PDF Files In Linux](https://ostechnix.com/create-video-pdf-files-linux/)
2. [Add audio to video using FFmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/590201/add-audio-to-video-using-ffmpeg)
3. [Copying the audio without re-encoding](https://superuser.com/a/277667/257269)

#### Final remark

Note that a `pptx` file is a `zip` file. If you rename into `zip` and you extract with its subfolders, you will be able to find the **media** included, original audio files too, and to use these to *build* your video.

Comment: well this almost solves my problem. The main issue is that the audio files on each slide are of variable lengths, which your solution doesn't quite solve. It gets very close. It was nice to know the info stated under Final Remark. Really helpful

Comment: _That has not (yet) been directly-implemented (IMK)._  BTW, once you extracted audio and converted into pictures the slides (with the desired video definition), with a Video Editing Program you will have the complete control: you can add the audio tracks one after the other, add the pause you need between, then add the _video_ importing the picture for the needed time... It is an overkill, but it will ensure the best and lossless procedure. The _Screen recorder_ or the _Video conferencing software_ solutions may work too, but you have to be careful to avoid if possible audio re-encoding.